# Manually change order of y axis items on complicated stacked bar chart in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've been stuck on an issue and can't find a solution.  I've tried many suggestions on Stack Overflow and elsewhere about manually ordering a stacked bar chart, since that should be a pretty simple fix, but those suggestions don't work with the huge complicated mess of code I plucked from many places.  My only issue is y-axis item ordering.

I'm making a series of stacked bar charts, and ggplot2 changes the ordering of the items on the y-axis depending on which dataframe I am trying to plot.  I'm trying to make 39 of these plots and want them to all have the same ordering.  I think ggplot2 only wants to plot them in ascending order of their numeric mean or something, but I'd like all of the bar charts to first display the group "Bird Advocates" and then "Cat Advocates."  (This is also the order they appear in my data frame, but that ordering is lost at the coord_flip() point in plotting.)

I think that taking the data frame through so many changes is why I can't just add something simple at the end or use the reorder() function.  Adding things into aes() also doesn't work, since the stacked bar chart I'm creating seems to depend on those items being exactly a certain way.

Here's one of my data frames where ggplot2 is ordering my y-axis items incorrectly, plotting "Cat Advocates" before "Bird Advocates":

```
Group,Strongly Opposed,Opposed,Slightly Opposed,Neutral,Slightly Support,Support,Strongly Support
Bird Advocates,0.005473026,0.010946052,0.012509773,0.058639562,0.071149335,0.31118061,0.530101642
Cat Advocates,0.04491726,0.07013396,0.03624901,0.23719464,0.09141056,0.23404255,0.28605201
```

And here's all the code that takes that and turns it into a plot:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
library(plotly)

#Importing data from a .csv file
data <- read.csv("data.csv", header=TRUE)

data$s.Strongly.Opposed <- 0-data$Strongly.Opposed-data$Opposed-data$Slightly.Opposed-.5*data$Neutral
data$s.Opposed <- 0-data$Opposed-data$Slightly.Opposed-.5*data$Neutral
data$s.Slightly.Opposed <- 0-data$Slightly.Opposed-.5*data$Neutral
data$s.Neutral <- 0-.5*data$Neutral
data$s.Slightly.Support <- 0+.5*data$Neutral
data$s.Support <- 0+data$Slightly.Support+.5*data$Neutral
data$s.Strongly.Support <- 0+data$Support+data$Slightly.Support+.5*data$Neutral

#to percents
data[,2:15]<-data[,2:15]*100

#melting
mdfr <- melt(data, id=c("Group"))
mdfr<-cbind(mdfr[1:14,],mdfr[15:28,3])
colnames(mdfr)<-c("Group","variable","value","start")

#remove dot in level names
mylevels<-c("Strongly Opposed","Opposed","Slightly Opposed","Neutral","Slightly Support","Support","Strongly Support")
mdfr$variable<-droplevels(mdfr$variable)
levels(mdfr$variable)<-mylevels

pal<-c("#bd7523", "#e9aa61", "#f6d1a7", "#999999", "#c8cbc0", "#65806d", "#334e3b")

ggplot(data=mdfr) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = Group, y = start, xend = Group, yend = start+value, colour = variable,
                   text=paste("Group: ",Group,"<br>Percent: ",value,"%")), size = 5) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, color =c("#646464")) +
  coord_flip() + 
  theme(legend.position="top") +
  theme(legend.key.width=unit(0.5,"cm")) +
  guides(col = guide_legend(ncol = 12)) + #has 7 real columns, using to adjust legend position 
  scale_color_manual("Response", labels = mylevels, values = pal, guide="legend") +
  theme(legend.title = element_blank()) +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank()) +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_blank()) +
  theme(axis.ticks = element_blank()) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank()) +
  theme(legend.key = element_rect(fill = "white")) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(-100,100,100), limits=c(-100,100)) +  
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "#ffffff"),
        panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "#CBCBCB"))
```

The plot:
[image: Link to plot]

Comment: It's hard to do without working data - using something like `dput(data)` would be useful.

Comment: Have you tried something like  `scale_x_manual(breaks = c('bird advocates', 'cat advocates'))` or `ggplot(data, aes(reorder('bird advocates', 'cat advocates')`?

Comment: I pasted the plaintext version of the .csv file I'm importing.  I don't know how to upload a .csv file to Stack Exchange.  I tried your solutions, which are similar to things I tried earlier, but they don't work.  As my post said, anything I've tried to put into the aes() part of ggplot won't work with my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this works, you may need to play around with the axis limits/breaks:

```
library(dplyr)

mdfr <- mdfr %>%
  mutate(group_n = as.integer(case_when(Group == "Bird Advocates" ~ 2,
                         Group == "Cat Advocates" ~ 1)))

ggplot(data=mdfr) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = group_n, y = start, xend = group_n, yend = start + value, colour = variable,
               text=paste("Group: ",Group,"<br>Percent: ",value,"%")), size = 5) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0,3), breaks = c(1, 2), labels = c("Cat", "Bird")) + 
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, color =c("#646464")) +
  theme(legend.position="top") +
  theme(legend.key.width=unit(0.5,"cm")) +
 coord_flip() + 
  guides(col = guide_legend(ncol = 12)) + #has 7 real columns, using to adjust legend position 
  scale_color_manual("Response", labels = mylevels, values = pal, guide="legend") +
  theme(legend.title = element_blank()) +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank()) +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_blank()) +
  theme(axis.ticks = element_blank()) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank()) +
  theme(legend.key = element_rect(fill = "white"))+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(-100,100,100), limits=c(-100,100)) +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "#ffffff"),
    panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "#CBCBCB"))
```

produces this plot:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for that fix!  None of the normal methods of changing axis ordering were working.

Answer (score 0):

You want to factor the 'Group' variable in the order by which you want the bars to appear.

```
mdfr$Group <- factor(mdfr$Group, levels = c("Bird Advocates", "Cat Advocates")
```

Comment: Thank you, but I'd tried something like that earlier.  Adding your line at the end of the #melting section of code makes the whole chart not work, and adding it after the #remove dot in levels section doesn't change the y-axis ordering.

Comment: sorry, I've had similar situations and that always seems to resolve it so figured I'd try that first. I'm not doubting it didn't work but I am not sure why it would make a difference in where you described it to be placed. so long as it is after colnames(mdfr) line in #melting section it should not make difference in how it affects your output

Comment: Thanks anyway.  I realize this should be a no brainer issue to fix, but something about all the code I'm using is preventing me from being able to use standard fixes.